# Type inference strangeness

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, type-inference

So I have a `Tuple2` class as follows:

```
public final class Tuple2<T1, T2> {
   private final T1 mItem1;
   private final T2 mItem2;

   public T1 getItem1() { return mItem1; }
   public T2 getItem2() { return mItem2; }

   public Tuple2(final T1 pItem1, final T2 pItem2) {
      mItem1 = pItem1;
      mItem2 = pItem2;
   }

   public static <TItem1, TItem2> Tuple2<TItem1, TItem2>
   Create(final TItem1 pItem1, final TItem2 pItem2) {
      return new Tuple2<>(pItem1, pItem2);
   }
}
```

and I'm trying to instantiate a `List` of `Tuple2`s, but the type inference seems way weird. I would expect I could do something like this:

```
// doesn't work
// note that Type2 extends Type1, and Type3 extends Type2
final List<Tuple2<String, Class<?>>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.Create("1", Type1.class),
   Tuple2.Create("2", Type2.class),
   Tuple2.Create("3", Type3.class)
);

// still doesn't work
final List<Tuple2<String, Class<? extends Type1>>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.Create("1", Type1.class),
   Tuple2.Create("2", Type2.class),
   Tuple2.Create("3", Type3.class)
);
```

Neither of these work if I cast to `Class<?>` or to `Class<? extends Type1>` either.

What it requires me to do instead is:

```
final List<Tuple2<String, ? extends Class<? extends Type1>>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.Create("1", Type1.class),
   Tuple2.Create("2", Type2.class),
   Tuple2.Create("3", Type3.class)
);
```

But then if I want to define a reference to one of these `Tuple2`s I have to write:

```
final Tuple2<String, ? extends Class<? extends Type1>> item = list.get(0);
```

That is one ugly type name... Is there a way to simplify this? Why does it have to be a `Tuple2` "of something that extends `Class` of something that extends `Type1`", rather than simply "of `Class` of something"?

The only simpler way I've found is using the `Class` raw type, which seems to be discouraged, and needs some casting:

```
final List<Tuple2<String, Class>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.Create("1", (Class)Type1.class),
   Tuple2.Create("2", (Class)Type2.class),
   Tuple2.Create("3", (Class)Type3.class)
);
final Tuple2<String, Class> item = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old [generic invariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) rearing its head again.

For each call to `Create`, the types are inferred as:

```
<String, Class<Type1>>
<String, Class<Type2>>
<String, Class<Type3>>
```

As you may know, a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>` and the same concept applies here. A `Tuple2<String, Class<Type1>>` is not a `Tuple2<String, Class<?>>` but it is a `Tuple2<String, ? extends Class<?>>`.

So for the three inferred `Tuple2` types:

```
Tuple2<String, Class<Type1>>
Tuple2<String, Class<Type2>>
Tuple2<String, Class<Type3>>
```

The type they have in common is `Tuple2<String, ? extends Class<? extends Type1>>`.

As far as I know the only way around this is to supply a type witness for each call:

```
final List<Tuple2<String, Class<?>>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.<String, Class<?>>Create("1", Type1.class),
   Tuple2.<String, Class<?>>Create("2", Type2.class),
   Tuple2.<String, Class<?>>Create("3", Type3.class)
);
```

That should work.

It seems like this *should* work:

```
final List<Tuple2<String, Class<?>>> list = Arrays.asList(
   Tuple2.Create("1", (Class<?>)Type1.class),
   Tuple2.Create("2", (Class<?>)Type2.class),
   Tuple2.Create("3", (Class<?>)Type3.class)
);
```

But it doesn't compile. The compiler does capture conversion and infers the `Class<?>` as `Class<capture of ?>`. So the inferred types you end up with are something like:

```
<String, Class<capture #1 of ?>>
<String, Class<capture #2 of ?>>
<String, Class<capture #3 of ?>>
```

And still three distinct types from each other.

I will be honest: I have no idea why it works that way, just that it does. I have been unable to find a definitive answer to that. [The spec says this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10):

> - If T<sub>i</sub> is a wildcard type argument [...] of the form ?, then S<sub>i</sub> is a **fresh** type variable [...].

Which seems to imply that `capture of ?` is considered as a new type and distinct from `?`.

It seems to me that inference just has a gap with respect to the wildcard as of version 7.

Comment: thanks, that's not as clean as I'd like it, but it's slightly better. (although I was using the static method to get the type inference, I may as well use the constructor in this case if that's the best I can get). Why can't I cast `TypeX.class` to `Class<?>`?

Comment: See my edit: Unfortunately, I don't really have a good answer as to why exactly this is the case but I gave my understanding of it.